# Word Macro, select and append to bolded texts

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have word file that looks like the following:

---

**Title1** This is text for title 1.

**Title Two 2** This is text for title 2.

... and so on ...

---

Now I want to add a hyphen after the bolded texts so that it looks like the following:

---

**Title1**- This is text for title 1.

**Title Two 2**- This is text for title 2.

---

This is assuming that bolded words only appear in the beginning of the paragraph. I use the following macro to loop through the paragraphs but I don't know how to select the bolded phrase.

```
Sub parser()
'
' parser Macro
'
'
    
    Dim Doc As Document: Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim Para As Paragraph
    
    For Each Para In Doc.Paragraphs
        If Para.Range.Characters.Count > 8 Then
            currPara = Replace(Para.Range.Text, Chr(13), "")
            ' ^ want to do something similar to find bold phrases
            ' and add hyphen
            Debug.Print currPara
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please follow these guidelines and your chance to get help will increase:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the Style of these Title text elements? By Style I mean is it a Heading style or something else? I ask because it might be a better why to programmatically search for the Style name and then edit the existing text from that point.

Comment: @RichMichaels Sadly there are no styles, it is a plain text (style normal) with bold phrases in the beginning of each paragraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already haven’t figured it out ... this will work:

```
Sub FindBoldedTitles()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim para As Word.Range
    
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        While .Execute
            Set para = rng.Paragraphs(1).Range
            If para.Characters.First.InRange(rng) Then
                If para.Characters.Last.Bold = False And _
                   Not rng.Characters.Last.Text = "-" Then
                    rng.InsertAfter " -"
                End If
            End If
            rng.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! However, when I have a large file this takes forever because it is looping through each paragraph. Is there any way to optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    If .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Start Then
      Do While .Characters.Last Like "[ " & Chr(11) & Chr(160) & vbTab & vbCr & "]"
        .End = .End - 1
      Loop
      .InsertAfter "-"
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This'll do it for a document as described:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
  Call SearchBoldTextAndInsertHyphen
End Sub

Sub SearchBoldTextAndInsertHyphen()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisDocument.Range(0, 0)
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Font.Bold = True
        While .Execute
            rng.InsertAfter (" -")
        Wend
    End With
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code will add a hyphen after every find of bolded text.  The OP specifically states that they only want the hyphen inserting for bold text at the start of a paragraph.

Comment: Well, now he has some base code to elaborate upon. This is not a programming service where  push-button ready code is delivered. I guess that's the reason you downvoted a perfectly working code for further development.

Comment: TS specifically wrote: "want to do something similar to find bold phrases and add hyphen"
My solution solves that part.

Comment: @StureS I am not the one that downvoted, I am yet to look at this. Will have to test it out first. And my question also got downvoted. Am I not supposed to ask this question?

Comment: @pewpewlasers Most people here are very talented and answer questions in a proper way. However, some people are here only to complain which does not add to the solution. It's a risk we have to take.
I upvoted you back.

Comment: In the Sub SearchBoldTextAndInsertHyphen(), you can supply a range argument to limit the search